# How do I prevent writing the same code? Unable to correctly write the decorator. Python

Tags: python-3.x, flask

This is my code that is working fine. I am using unittest in Flask. I don't want to repeat the same code over and over again in every method.

```
def setUp(self):
    self.ctx = app.app_context()

def test_check_data_cleanup_functionality(self):
    with self.ctx:
        g.db_client = main_client["some_text"]
        test_json["stray"] = "abc"
        view = View.objects.get(name="test_document")
        all_fields = get_all_fields(DocumentDefinition.objects.get(name="test_document"))
        status = sanity_check(test_json, view, all_fields, old_collection=None, parent_field_id="")
        self.assertFalse(status[0]["error"])
```

However, for every method, I don't want to type the same code,

```
 with self.ctx:
        g.db_client = main_client["some_text"]
```

How do I go about it? I tried creating a decorator but for some reason I am not able to get the correct syntax or the logic. I tried various tutorials but am unable to do so. Do help. My decorator code below.

```
def timing_function(some_function):
        def wrapper(some_function_):
            with app.app_context():
                g.db_client = main_client["some_text"]
                some_function()
        return wrapper  


@timing_function
 def test_check_unique(self):
        test_json["single_line_field"] = "Hello!"
        view = View.objects.get(name="test_document")
        all_fields = get_all_fields(DocumentDefinition.objects.get(name="test_document"))
        status = sanity_check(test_json, view, all_fields, old_collection=None, parent_field_id="")
        self.assertTrue(status[0]["error"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for a simple decorator:

```
def timing_function(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        with app.app_context():
            g.db_client = main_client["ondotfreight"]
            func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

The decorator takes a `func` and returns whatever should replace it. To make it as general as possible, the inner (replacement) function takes `*args` and `**kwargs`, but this can be specialized.

It uses globals like `g` and `app`, which makes the decorator very dependent on the environement it's being used inside, but if your code without the decorator worked, then this should, too.

Assuming you would then want to add parameters to the decorator, for example to pass the key that goes into `main_client`, it would look like this:

```
def timing_function(main_client_name)
    def wrapper_gen(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                g.db_client = main_client[main_client_name]
                func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return wrapper_gen
```

Here you first create a decorator from the arguments, before this decorator then is applied to the function, like in the normal case without arguments. With this you can do:

```
@timing_function("ondotfreight")
def test_check_unique(self):
    # ...
```